# Why does this `std::atomic_thread_fence` work

Tags: c++, x86, memory-barriers, stdatomic

Firstly I want to list some of my undertandings regarding to this, please correct me if I'm wrong.

1. a `MFENCE` in x86 can ensure a full barrier
2. Sequential-Consistency prevents reordering of STORE-STORE, STORE-LOAD, LOAD-STORE and LOAD-LOAD

   This is according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_ordering).
3. `std::memory_order_seq_cst` makes no guarantee to prevent STORE-LOAD reorder.

   This is according to [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053600/does-standard-c11-guarantee-that-memory-order-seq-cst-prevents-storeload-reord?rq=1), "Loads May Be Reordered with Earlier Stores to Different Locations"(for x86) and mfence will not always be added.

   Whether a `std::memory_order_seq_cst` indicates Sequential-Consistency? According to point 2/3, it seems not correct to me. `std::memory_order_seq_cst` indicates  Sequential-Consistency only when

   1. at least one explicit `MFENCE` added to either `LOAD` or `STORE`
   2. LOAD (without fence) and LOCK XCHG
   3. LOCK XADD ( 0 ) and STORE (without fence)

   otherwise there will still be possible reorders.

   **According to @LWimsey's comment, I made a mistake here, if both the `LOAD` and `STORE` are `memory_order_seq_cst`, there's no reorder. Alex may indicated situations where non-atomic or non-SC is used.**
4. `std::atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_seq_cst)` always generates a full-barrier

   This is according to [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478029/does-atomic-thread-fencememory-order-seq-cst-have-the-semantics-of-a-full-memo). So I can always replace `asm volatile("mfence" ::: "memory")` with `std::atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_seq_cst)`

   This is quite strange to me, because a `memory_order_seq_cst` seems to have quite a difference usage between atomic functions and fence functions.

Now I come to this code in header file  of MSVC 2015's standard library, which implements `std::atomic_thread_fence`

```
inline void _Atomic_thread_fence(memory_order _Order)
    {   /* force memory visibility and inhibit compiler reordering */
 #if defined(_M_ARM) || defined(_M_ARM64)
    if (_Order != memory_order_relaxed)
        {
        _Memory_barrier();
        }

 #else
    _Compiler_barrier();
    if (_Order == memory_order_seq_cst)
        {   /* force visibility */
        static _Uint4_t _Guard;
        _Atomic_exchange_4(&_Guard, 0, memory_order_seq_cst);
        _Compiler_barrier();
        }
 #endif
    }
```

So my major question is how can `_Atomic_exchange_4(&_Guard, 0, memory_order_seq_cst);` create a full barrier `MFENCE`, or what has actually done to enable an equivalent mechanism like `MFENCE`, because a `_Compiler_barrier()` is obviously not enough here for a full memory barrier, or this statement works somewhat similar to point 3?

Comment: About your point 3 "_std::memory_order_seq_cst makes no guarantee to prevent STORE-LOAD reorder_".. It does guarantee that, but only when both operations are tagged as such.

Comment: @LWimsey Do you mean if I use `atomic_store(memory_order_seq_cst )` and `atomic_load(memory_order_seq_cst )`, there'll be no reorder. However if I use `atomic_store(memory_order_release)` and `atomic_load(memory_order_acquire)`, then I should add a `MFENCE` to either of them, in order to avoid STORE-LOAD reorder?

Comment: Yes, if you use `seq_cst` on both the `store` and the `load`, all threads will observe both operations in that order. The same for inserting an `atomic_thread_fence(seq_cst)` in between (You can/should not really insert an `MFENCE`, leave that to the compiler).

Comment: @calvin It actually depends on whether or not you talk about the same memory location. If you do an `x.store(1, memory_order_release); x.load(memory_order_acquire);` then no fence would needed (although such a construct would be highly questionable, so you probably meant them to be on different memory locations).

Comment: @LWimsey 1) All threads? Which threads? 2) Fence between what and what? Other threads must use the fence?

Comment: @LWimsey: you can use `atomic_thread_fence(seq_cst)` after some normal stores, before an atomic `.store(val, mo_relaxed)`, to effectively create a release store.  Or after a store to make it more like a `.store(val, mo_seq_cst)`.  ISO C++ doesn't define things in terms of reordering or not so I'm hesitant to say it stops it from reordering with later atomic loads and stores.  For the first use-case to work, it does need to block compile-time reordering with non-atomic operations in some cases.

Comment: And yes, as an implementation detail it's allowed for it to be stronger, and actually block all reordering including non-atomic, at compile time.  (And of course run-time with `mfence`)

Comment: @PeterCordes  An `atomic_thread_fence(seq_cst)` _after_ a `.store(val, mo_relaxed)` does not make it a `.store(val, mo_seq_cst)` because it does not have `release` semantics and that's required (unless you take into account `x86` specs)

Comment: @LWimsey: I was trying not to fill up two 600 char comments saying that in detail, but "more like mo_seq_cst" was too vague.  So yes, you could barrier before *and* after a .store(mo_relaxed) to get an inefficient seq_cst store.  Or I guess just after a `release` store, at least on x86 if not in portable ISO C++.  Perhaps not exactly equivalent on other ISAs that aren't multi-copy-atomic (notably POWER); I forget if POWER needs stronger barriers before a seq_cst store than before a release store.

Comment: @PeterCordes Barriers around a relaxed operation is an (inefficient) way to prevent reordering, that is to get acquire resp. release semantics; but it doesn't make the operation globally sequentially consistent. At most the fences are "sequentially consistent" (but then, you don't observe fences, only stores, directly, and loads, indirectly, via the side effects the code following them produce).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So my major question is how can `_Atomic_exchange_4(&_Guard, 0, memory_order_seq_cst);` create a full barrier MFENCE

This compiles to an `xchg` instruction with a memory destination.  This is a full memory barrier (draining the store buffer) exactly<sup>1</sup> like `mfence`.

With compiler barriers before and after that, compile-time reordering around it is also prevented.  Therefore all reordering in either direction is prevented (of operations on atomic and non-atomic C++ objects), making it more than strong enough to do everything that ISO C++ `atomic_thread_fence(mo_seq_cst)` promises.

---

For orders weaker than seq_cst, only a compiler barrier is needed.  x86's hardware memory-ordering model is program-order + a store buffer with store forwarding.  That's strong enough for `acq_rel` without the compiler emitting any special asm instructions, just blocking compile-time reordering.  https://preshing.com/20120930/weak-vs-strong-memory-models/

---

**Footnote 1**: exactly enough for the purposes of std::atomic.  Weakly ordered MOVNTDQA loads from WC memory may not be as strictly ordered by `lock`ed instructions as by MFENCE.

- [Which is a better write barrier on x86: lock+addl or xchgl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232660/which-is-a-better-write-barrier-on-x86-lockaddl-or-xchgl/52910647#52910647)
- [Does lock xchg have the same behavior as mfence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40409297/does-lock-xchg-have-the-same-behavior-as-mfence) - equivalent for std::atomic purposes, but some minor differences that might matter for a device driver using WC memory regions.  And perf differences.  Notably [on Skylake where `mfence` blocks OoO exec like `lfence`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50494658/are-loads-and-stores-the-only-instructions-that-gets-reordered)
- [Why is LOCK a full barrier on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60332591/why-is-lock-a-full-barrier-on-x86)

Atomic read-modify-write (RMW) operation on x86 are only possible with a `lock` prefix, or [`xchg` with memory](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/xchg) which is like that even without a lock prefix in the machine code.  A lock-prefixed instruction (or xchg with mem) is always a full memory barrier.

Using an instruction like `lock add dword [esp], 0` as a substitute for `mfence` is a well-known technique.  (And performs better on some CPUs.)  **This MSVC code is the same idea, but instead of a no-op on whatever the stack pointer is pointing-to, it does an `xchg` on a dummy variable**.  It doesn't actually matter where it is, but a cache line that's only ever accessed by the current core and is already hot in cache is the best choice for performance.

**Using a `static` shared variable that all cores will contend for access to is the worst possible choice; this code is terrible!**  Interacting with the same cache line as other cores is not necessary to control the order of this core's operations on its own L1d cache.  This is completely bonkers.  MSVC still apparently uses this horrible code in its implementation of `std::atomic_thread_fence()`, even for x86-64 where `mfence` is guaranteed available.  ([Godbolt with MSVC 19.14](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tLgFZSW9ABk8tTADljAI0zEQADlIAHVAsLqtHqGJuY%2BfgF0tvZORq7uXkoqanQMBMzEBMHGppwWSZiqgWkZBNGOLm6eiumZ2aF5NaXlsfGeAJSKqAbEyBwA5FIAzHbIhlgA1OJDOsxERngSQ9jiAAwAgmvrAG6oeOgTzhnEeG4Q7VMA7LIbE3cTCgToICBzqAvIAPoECMSYzOhPlQtH0II9niAjJgjCQAJ6fEhYYifJQAR0%2ByEe7WmN02lwAIlstrt9g8iH8UcgwU8Xm8PtMdHYCNNsFNJAA2bYZC7ia5be4TLnEKZDfETTiSIY4okE/qdVggfpmfqkUz9VYq1CKnRyOQPbq9TBsoacFUERUa9qdBD/JGUToAaxAQ24ADoAJwednu7hmTjey4SrwK/rcFVqjWkLX9FUKECrUjm9Vy0hwWBINBGbx4dhkCgQTPZ3MoVifewAd0%2B7N4VBzBDccYgzgtKucdgysMVptImah9AA8rRWJ3k6QsEYRMB2C2x3g/kVtpg46PMAAPQoGetdlVM5Qz1h4ZzEDt6LDbxMnIzbzo0ehMNgcHj8QTCUQoXUyISHuOQTqobwpLQy4ALT9pIsbKIUgGaNo9S5JY2gtJU7icOE/iAXBgi%2BOhgRIXEVSoQURSpLUWT6DkghEYBJSZHhbSEaRmEMc0dgVPhKGdAoBp9Fw8qKsqqoztGq7VhMRgKNsyCCpw7qujwEwQAA6gAkg42AXBAuCECQxqoRMehZjmbi6RcOoyHIZotp0EAZu8RZuOQlCFkZ7iLMgMmobWrD1sQjbNqOba0B2569loBCDsOM7jpO06jvg85qIuy6RmuG5bv03a7iGkYHkeJ4YAM3YEJe16kLejAsNOT4CEMQiTu%2B5mfrlP7nFGAGBCB/ZDBBySBDBujkQ0CE2KxrQEWhkRBIN8HYZNdHjVRxSMdNlGQcRtA0WUo3IZRy0hPBjwsTEO2cJx3GPnxSrhkJiqrl6wGiW54qyasckKVp5K6aQ%2Bl2S5xpDKZH7SJZyZWqQTpDJIrpmKs7JmJIlzcHkPBDOyQiKmGgmjtGsbxomVmpjAiAoL9uaOQWpNVMA7q1V5Pl%2BTOgXBRlKqhQOQ4jpG0WiLFXNzlBeBJTOqXIJuhU7vQe6jrlx7ELCp7ixeeBXizN50BVD5cLwAiSHVb4SI18jNfAf7tXQnXdYoa3QRAVhMcN80oRNGErahs2AY7q29SRpT24tPu0dt7G7b7rtNIHx3B6dXQ9Dx0chgJEaard92icAyBSbJQzvfgn3DHpBn2cKwySIDhsg5a1q2lUrUQ1DMNwwjSN%2BtwqPo6G13Y4quMJkmlft%2BBWORjj%2BOg50i6%2BX13BAA))

If you're doing a seq_cst *store*, your options are `mov`+`mfence` (gcc does this) or doing the store *and* the barrier with a single `xchg` (clang and MSVC do this, so the codegen is fine, no shared dummy var).

---

**Much of the early part of this question (stating "facts") seems wrong and contains some misinterpretations or things that are so misguided they're not even wrong.**

> `std::memory_order_seq_cst` makes no guarantee to prevent STORE-LOAD reorder.

C++ guarantees order using a totally different model, where acquire loads that see a value from a release store "synchronize with" it, and later operations in the C++ source are guaranteed to see all the stores from code before the release store.

It also guarantees that there's a total order of *all* seq_cst operations even across different objects.  (Weaker orders allow a thread to reload its own stores before they become globally visible, i.e. store forwarding. That's why only seq_cst has to drain the store buffer.  They also allow IRIW reordering.  [Will two atomic writes to different locations in different threads always be seen in the same order by other threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27807118/will-two-atomic-writes-to-different-locations-in-different-threads-always-be-see/50679223#50679223))

Concepts like StoreLoad reordering are based on a model where:

- All inter-core communication is via committing stores to cache-coherent shared memory
- Reordering happens inside one core between its own accesses to cache.  e.g. by the store buffer delaying store visibility until after later loads like x86 allows.  (Except a core can see its own stores early via store forwarding.)

**In terms of this model, seq_cst does require draining the store buffer at some point between a seq_cst store and a later seq_cst load**.  The efficient way to implement this is to put a full barrier *after* seq_cst stores.  (Instead of before every seq_cst load.  Cheap loads are more important than cheap stores.)

On an ISA like AArch64, there are load-acquire and store-release instructions which actually have sequential-release semantics, unlike x86 loads/stores which are "only" regular release.  (So AArch64 seq_cst doesn't need a separate barrier; a microarchitecture could delay draining the store buffer unless / until a load-acquire executes while there's still a store-release not committed to L1d cache yet.)  Other ISAs generally need a full barrier instruction to drain the store buffer after a seq_cst store.

Of course even AArch64 needs a full barrier instruction for a `seq_cst` *fence*, unlike a `seq_cst` load or store *operation*.

---

> `std::atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_seq_cst)` always generates a full-barrier

In practice yes.

> So I can always replace `asm volatile("mfence" ::: "memory")` with `std::atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_seq_cst)`

In practice yes, but in theory an implementation could maybe allow some reordering of non-atomic operations around `std::atomic_thread_fence` and still be standards-compliant.  *Always* is a very strong word.

ISO C++ only guarantees anything when there are `std::atomic` load or store operations involved.  GNU C++ would let you roll your own atomic operations out of `asm("" ::: "memory")` compiler barriers (acq_rel) and `asm("mfence" ::: "memory")` full barriers.  Converting that to ISO C++ signal_fence and thread_fence would leave a "portable" ISO C++ program that has data-race UB and thus no guarantee of anything.

(Although note that rolling your own atomics should use [at least `volatile`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557979/when-to-use-volatile-with-multi-threading/58535118#58535118), not just barriers, to make sure the compiler doesn't invent multiple loads, even if you avoid the obvious problem of having loads hoisted out of a loop.  [Who's afraid of a big bad optimizing compiler?](https://lwn.net/Articles/793253/)).

---

**Always remember that what an implementation does has to be *at least* as strong as what ISO C++ guarantees.  That often ends up being stronger.**

Comment: Any reason to prefer exactly `XCHG` and exactly static storage duration variable (which is actually not stored on stack)? I suspect it is due to having smallest encoding (no `LOCK` prefix, simple address obtaining). And so change to `LOCK CMPXCHG` in later MSVC is not useful, though not very harmful.

Comment: I know they also don't use `mfence` because they run on CPUs without `mfence` (at least used to run in theory), so even if `mfence` had better performance, they probably would not use it

Comment: @AlexGuteniev: oh holy crap, I only skimmed the code and only saw what I expected to see.  Not the insane code that's actually there (`static`), which is vastly worse and creates contention between separate cores doing a barrier.  `mfence` is baseline for x86-64 so that would be an option, and smaller code than having to zero a reg for `xchg`.  You might still choose a dummy `xchg` or other locked operation as a more efficient barrier for some CPUs.  But a dummy xchg with a *stack* variable would be totally fine, perhaps making it `volatile` if necessary to stop it from optimizing away.

Comment: xor-zeroing EAX + `xchg [rsp+disp8]` is I think equal size to `lock add [rsp+disp8], 0`.  (2-byte xor-zeroing vs. 1 byte lock + one byte for the imm8=0 on top of the same opcode + modrm + disp8 for xchg or add)

Comment: I thought if you increment a dummy stack atomic by 1, and would discard returned value, compilers would be able to use `lock inc`, but apparently they are not.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev: GCC uses `lock inc` for atomic `++` when you compile with a tune option that tunes for a CPU where `inc` is totally fine on registers.  e.g. `-mtune=haswell`.  https://godbolt.org/z/fWMhMB.  Unfortunately it uses memory-destination `inc` even in the non-locked case, which costs an extra uop on Haswell.  [INC instruction vs ADD 1: Does it matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36510095).

Comment: @AlexGuteniev: MSVC uses `xadd` with a value in EAX, even when you aren't using the return value  of `var++` or `var += 0;`.  So that's dumb.  At least the MSVC under WIINE install on Godbolt which is all that's available today (https://github.com/mattgodbolt/compiler-explorer/issues/1929).  Presumably it's just as bad in current MSVC on real Windows, missing that peephole optimization.

Comment: I've reported the code being sub-optimal here: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/739 , further discussion of better code for MSVC would be more useful there

Comment: I brought this to the attention of Boost.Atomic maintainer, today he made [a commit](https://github.com/boostorg/atomic/commit/559eba81af71386cedd99f170dc6101c6ad7bf22). The most interesting part is an explanation **against** `lock or [esp], 0` in this link: https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/on-the-fence-with-dependencies/ . In short, there may be false data dependency in case of registers spilling.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev: Oh cool, using the dword or qword below the current stack point is something I suggested for GCC (https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-patches/2016-05/msg02289.html), but they reverted the change after finding that some analysis tools like valgrind complained.  I was curious what the real perf impact was, since in theory it's a full barrier and ends with the store buffer drained.  But in practice the CPU can probably still actually start loading sooner.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what happens in linked example either. I also now noticed that they have 4-byte dummy increment (lock **addl** $0x0,(%rsp)), but 8-byte load mov    (%rsp),**%rcx**. Does the problem happen on 8-byte dummy `or` ?

Comment: @AlexGuteniev: `lock add` vs. `lock or` is totally irrelevant.  I doubt that the operand-size matters either; by definition atomic RMWs are a full barrier so I assume they can't store-forward to a later load.  Non-atomic `orl $0, (%rsp)` *would* cause a store-forwarding stall if an 8-byte reloaded `(%rsp)` right away, but I assume the data just has to come from L1d cache after a `lock`ed operation that overlaps any bytes with the load.  So fully overlapping with one qword local var vs. partially overlapping the low dword doesn't matter.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev: However, narrower means you only overlap *one* dword, not two.  `lock orb $0, (%rsp)` might be better in that respect, in case you happen to only cause a penalty for `char_array[0]` instead of `char_array[0..3]`.  Of course qword operand size is a waste of a REX prefix and should be avoided for code-size reasons.  Oh also, the read side of an atomic RMW is maybe speculatively executed early.  *It* might benefit from store-forwarding, so narrower operand size makes that more compatible with more types that might be locals.  Byte being best, unless there's any downside to it.

Comment: I meant the case which breaks store-forwarding by loading 8 bytes after storing 4 bytes. As you noted, with atomic it should not be relevant, but if the information on given link is correct, then I suspect it might be somehow relevant. As I said, I don't understand (and don't care that much to try to conduct own experiments/investigations right now)

Comment: I'm also wondering if `_InterlockedOr(reinterpret_cast<volatile long*>(_AddressOfReturnAddress()), 0);` is vulnerable to the issue, but it is more theory question, I'm fine with extra variable.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev: TL:DR: `lock orq $0, (%rsp)` is the worst option.  It has at least a code-size downside, and maybe performance, vs. `lock orb $0, (%rsp)`  or `lock orl`.  I'd expect that `lock orb` is best, but `lock orb $0, -1(%rsp)` might be even better.  Or since space below RSP is dead on Windows x64 (no red zone), `lock orb %al, -1(%rsp)` is possible to save a byte, but with a false dependency on RAX.  Doing a locked op on the return address could work; branch prediction hides the latency of actually reloading it.

Comment: I think it deserves separate question and answer, instead of being in comments: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62337376/2945027

Comment: @PeterCordes Armv8.3+ supports reordering of _independent_ store-release and load-acquire (`LDAPRB`, `LDAPRH`, `LDAPR`), also [reference](https://community.arm.com/developer/ip-products/processors/b/processors-ip-blog/posts/armv8-a-architecture-2016-additions#Memory_consistency_model) (see Memory Consistency Model); Why does the above only satisfy acq_rel, and not seq_cst guarantees? i.e. we get release/acquire semantics, plus total order of stores, even though independent store/load may not be visible in source code order.

Comment: ^^ Just noticed that [the ref manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0487/latest/) section C6.2.102 on LDAPR says: _The reading of a value written by a Store-Release by a Load-AcquirePC instruction by the same observer
does not make the write of the Store-Release globally observed_; So STLR/LDAPR pair is plain old store-rel/read-acq without ordering guarantees; The store buffer is not drained after the store-rel or before the read-acq, not even for dependent load/store. If it was drained, then I guess it would satisfy seq_cst.

Comment: @DanielNitzan: Yeah, it's not seq_cst for exactly the same reason x86 needs `mfence` or a dummy `lock`ed operation as a full-barrier after seq_cst stores.  x86's standard memory model makes all loads + stores acq / rel, with a total store order.  It seems the point of v8.3 LDAPR and friends is to get acquire without draining the store buffer (seq_cst), for higher performance when used with release / seq_cst stores to other objects.  Including allowing store-forwarding from an STLR.  So it seems STLR / LDAPR is exactly like x86's standard memory model.

Comment: @PeterCordes ARM has gone so far as to provide a cheap seq_cst based on stlr/ldar, by having ldar inspect the store buffer for any stlr and flush the buffer if any exists. I'm wondering why they haven't gone the extra mile to make it even cheaper by having ldar look for stlr to the same address, and only if such stlr exists, then flush the store buffer. Obviously this complicates the circuitry, but it would be exactly seq_cst, no more no less.

Comment: @DanielNitzan: That would allow StoreLoad reordering and not be seq_cst.  https://preshing.com/20120515/memory-reordering-caught-in-the-act/.  I'm pretty sure ISO C++ `seq_cst` is strong enough to disallow the reordering in Preshing's example, by dint of requiring a total order for *all* seq_cst store and load operations.  I think ARM's `stlr` / `ldar` already is about (or exactly?) as weak as you can be and still be seq_cst.

Comment: @PeterCordes it's probably my misunderstanding, but Preshing's caught in the act doesn't in and of itself contradict C++11's seq_cst, which says nothing about StoreLoad reordering. It only requires read-acq/store-rel + TSO?

Comment: @DanielNitzan: On x86 (read-acq / store-rel + TSO), you *do* see memory reordering.  On a sequentially-consistent machine, you wouldn't; that's the literal definition of *sequential* consistency (everything appears to have happened in an order compatible with some interleaving of program order).  By using full barriers on x86, we can recover seq_cst (demonstrating the point of barriers).  You would need to invent some alternate way this litmus test could guarantee no reordering, but without flushing the store buffer between a seq_cst store and seq_cst load, for your idea to work.

Comment: @PeterCordes right, frankly ISO C++ definition of seq_cst confused me. I just couldn't find where the formal definition states that all operations need to take place in program order. I will try to dissect it more thoroughly just for fun

Comment: @DanielNitzan: See https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.multithread#intro.races-note-21 for a statement that the C++ rules *do* add up to giving that guarantee.  (For data-race-free programs).  See also https://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.order#note-5, and most importantly the preceding rule about the existence of a single total order on *all* seq_cst operations, and rules about that order being compatible with other orders like some forms of happens-before, including sequenced-before (program-order).

Comment: It's a bit of a mess to actually fully follow, but it's well known that C++ provides SC-DRF: sequential consistency (following the standard definition of that term which far precedes C++11), for Data Race Free programs.  [Memory Model in C++ : sequential consistency and atomicity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38425920)

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the pointers; I think that _strongly happens-before_ is used to stress the correct sequential order, as in _if A and B are memory_­order​::​seq_­cst operations and A strongly happens before B, then A precedes B in S_

Comment: This was brought up in SOF before, and also helps: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0668r5.html, especially the discussion about _sequenced before_ / _strongly happens before_

Comment: @DanielNitzan: Thanks for the link, I hadn't realized there were ISAs where `release` stores had problems synchronizing with `seq_cst` loads (although I guess only indirectly).  Yuck, I had assumed that seq_cst loads could safely be assumed to be a stronger version of acquire, like they are on most ISAs.  On x86, using release for pure stores is a win, but there's no motivation to weaken loads until you care about performance on other ISAs.  Except now you need to match acquire with release to even get correctness, at least in cases of transitive relations... Will have to look at that more.

Comment: @PeterCordes yeah, also the example program given to demonstrate broken compilation when leading fences are used, totally blows my mind. It just amazes me how scientists come to think of such complex scenarios given they rarely (never?) occur in practice.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like that the x86 implementation of the atomic STORE/LOAD operations takes advantage of the [strongly-ordered asm memory model of the x86 architecture](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/intel-memory-ordering-and-c++-memory-model.html).  See also [C/C++11 mappings to processors](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html)

The situation is very different on ARM, which the code snippet in the question demonstrates.

Herb Sutter made a great presentation on this for CPPCON 2014: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c1gO9aB9nbs

Comment: @mohammedwazeem - don't use `code formatting` for highlighting.  See [What could be done to stop code formatting misuse?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172458).  Your edit is harmful, and the people that approved it should have rejected it.

Comment: @PeterCordes Got it. Thanks for your valuable information.

Answer (score 0):

Just because a C++ fence is implemented as producing a particular assembly level fence, and in general needs to produce one, does not mean that you can go around hunting inline asm and replace explicit asm fence with C++ instructions!

C++ thread fences are called `std::atomic_thread_fence` for a reason: **they have a defined function solely in relation with `std::atomic<>` objects**.

You absolutely can't use these to order normal (non-atomic) memory operations.

> `std::memory_order_seq_cst` makes no guarantee to prevent STORE-LOAD
>   reorder.

It does but *only with respect to* other `std::memory_order_seq_cst` operations.

Comment: But how an exchange is synchronized with other atomics, in particular with `std::memory_order_seq_cst` load of another atomic (which is plain load in MSVC)? And I see it was replaced with `InterlockedCompareExhcange`, so didn't exchange work?

Comment: "_But how an exchange is synchronized with other atomics_" Specifically: an exchange done how?

Comment: I mean, this `atomic_thread_fence(seq_cst)` is implemented via exchange. and `atomic<T>::load(seq_cst))` is implemented via simple load with only compiler barriers around. How are they synchronized?